# Android things: failed to resolve PeripheralManagerService

Tags: raspberry-pi3, uart, android-things

I am trying to run a simple program for *Raspberry Pi 3* powered by *Android Things*. The program will try to read and write through serial port. When I try to get the *UART* device list, I get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/things/pio/PeripheralManagerService
```

To make it more clear:

[image]

Comment: Did you have `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.things"/>` line in your manifest file?

Answer (score 1):

Use latest version of Android Things which is

```
'com.google.android.things:androidthings:1.0'
```

and change PeripheralManagerService object into

```
PeripheralManager pioManager = PeripheralManager.getInstance()
```